# IE 8 doesn't work for me with grails+extjs4

Tags: extjs4

My application is quite ok in Forefox. But it doesn't work in IE 8.

Error------

```
Webpage error details
```

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; Tablet PC 2.0)
Timestamp: Sun, 13 Jan 2013 04:52:47 UTC

Message: 'isModel' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 452607
Code: 0
URI: ...://localhost:8088/rdptpl/static/js/ext/ext-all.js

I don't know where is my problem. Pls help.......

Comment: Install firebug light and check what the console says.

Comment: firebug console is ok. my application is quite ok and output is alright. but when i run it using IE , it couldn't start.

Comment: What I meant was that you add the firebug lite script to your app, and see what is wrong in IE.
http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Stable

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of HTML5 features in IE. [Here](http://html5test.com/) is the webpage to test html5 features in browsers. Could you please gives brief about HTML5 features used in your ExtJS application.

There are some HTML5 features implemented in ExtJS like Closable tabs, WebSQL, Local Storage and etc. ExtJS has alternate code for browsers to implement some of them HTML5 features. Local Storage and WebSQL can't be implemented in Internet Explorer.

Let me know